# How to fetch data in GoogleCharts [Symfony4]

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, google-visualization, symfony4

I use GoogleChartsBundle and I want to recover data that is in my database, for my example i want to see the number of candidat per categorie Like:

```
$pieChart = new PieChart();
$pieChart->getData()->setArrayToDataTable(
    [['Categorie', 'Number'],
     ['Categorie Web',     11],
     ['Categorie Mobile',      2]
    ]
);
```

This is work
but i want TO Add this in dynamics ( more categories ) i have tried this in **controller** but not working :
**updated**

```
 $data = null;
        foreach($categories as $categorie)
        {
            $data[] = array(
                $categorie->getTitre(), count($categorie->getCandidats()),
            );
        }
return $this->json($data);
        $pieChart = new PieChart();
        $pieChart->getData()->setArrayToDataTable(
            [$data]
        );
```

> PS : $data contain [["Web",1],["Mobile",1]], But in chart I see no data

this is example of the entity categorie and entity candidat

```
Entity Categorie
class Categorie
{ 
//...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Candidat", mappedBy="categorie")
     */
    private $candidats;

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getTitre();
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Candidat[]
 */
public function getCandidats(): Collection
{
    return $this->candidats;
}
```

//... getters and setters
}

Entity Candidat

class Candidat
{

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Categorie", inversedBy="candidats")
 */
private $categorie;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried whether there is data in your DB? What **exactly** do `$categories` and `$categories->getCandidats()` contain?

Comment: categories return all categories and categories->getCandidats() return all candidats of categories, i have added count(categories->getCandidats())

Comment: And what **exactly** does that contain? Data in the same format that worked before?

Comment: I have updated my question look section controller

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my probleme
I have edited this in controller

```
$data = [['Categorie','Nombre de candidats']];
    foreach($categories as $categorie)
    {
        $data[] = array(
            $categorie->getTitre(), count($categorie->getCandidats()),
        );
    }
    $pieChart = new PieChart();
    $pieChart->getData()->setArrayToDataTable(
        $data
    );
```